In rst file, how can I provide a link to file with %APPDATA% so it is independant of user?
I have link in a rst file that refers to a local file, which will be in a path dependant on user name, such as:
`The link to my file <file:///C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\AppData\\Local\\Apps\\myfile.html>`_

I am on a Windows OS, and this is a typical path that can be accessed with %APPDATA% in Explorer.
I would like to provide the link with something like:
`The link to my file <file:///%APPDATA%\\Apps\\myfile.html>`_

My try with %APPDATA% did not work. How should I do?
Edit: corrected %APPDATA% (added % at the variable end) and added _ at the end of the hyperlinks. However, that does not solve the real problem: the browser does not interpret / extend %APPDATA% so it answers "file not found".

Related: https://superuser.com/q/807835

The provided rST example has two problems: it uses C:%APPDATA\\… not C:%APPDATA%\\… and it misses the leading underscores (__) that would make it an anonymous indirect hyperlink. Try with a correct copy of the path that works in Explorer.

Thank you @g-milde. I edited the question to correct the typo I did when condensed things from the original .rst. I put only one _ at the end to have a non-anonymous hyperlink, bu that is a detail. In fact the real problems stays on: he browser does not interpret / extend %APPDATA% so it answers "file not found".

Here, the reference provided by mzjn comes into play: "file:// was deprecated greatly many years ago, due to the security implications of allowing a remote site ANY access to your file system. I think with IE, file:// still works, but only if it's from an local, or perhaps a trusted Intranet page. " It turns out to be a problem of HTML hyperlinking, not reStructuredText.

Yeah, I guess the answer is then... this in not possible, tell the user to copy-paste %APPDATA%\Apps\myfile.html into a Windows Explorer

In short: this is not possible
A workaround is to provide the link with %APPDATA% included and tell the user to copy-paste it into a Windows Explorer. So in rst:
To open 'the file', please copy-paste the following link into a Windows Explorer:
`file:///%APPDATA%\\Apps\\myfile.html`

In details:
From comments of mzdn and G. Milde.
From related: superuser.com/q/807835 (provided by @mzjn)

file:// was deprecated greatly many years ago, due to the security
implications of allowing a remote site ANY access to your file system.

So, it turns out to be a problem of HTML hyperlinking, not reStructuredText.
I guess the answer is then... this in not possible, tell the user to copy-paste %APPDATA%\Apps\myfile.html into a Windows Explorer.
